# Detect if iOS app restored from iCloud backup

Tags: ios, backup, icloud

Is there any way to detect if the launch is from a iCloud backup? (restored)

I have looked [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/) but there is nothing about it.

Their rules about what is allowed to backup is very strict(rejected multiple times for it) backing a database up, with just one user-generated change in it - now I have to back the data up somewhere else and reinsert it on restore from backup.

Comment: Did you ever find out if this is possible?

Comment: No I never found a way to detect it.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessiblealwaysthisdeviceonly

Keychain items can be marked as not to be backed up by using one of the accessible attribute with “ThisDeviceOnly”.

You could write a flag to NSUserDefaults and Keychain (Using kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly), whenever the keychain item is missing but the user defaults value is present (or a backed up keychain item) then it must have been restored from backup. Be aware of secure and not secure iTunes backups as a scenario too. Insecure backups shouldn’t have any keychain items.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is "Detect if iOS app restored from iCloud backup".

Comment: Store a backed up and not backed up value in keychain (or a mix of keychain and usersefaults) using APIs above. If only the backed up value is present on launch - then the app has been restored from backup.

Comment: Oh this is awesome thanks for the solution. Thats what I was searching for.

Comment: it may be worth to mention a crucial detail: if the restoration happens on the __same__ device the values marked with `kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly`  will be still there after restoration, because it is still _thisDeviceOnly_ – it is better to use the secure-enclace to "lose" information during restoration, as the secure-enclave will be purged for sure regardless anything.

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to check if a file in the document dir with `.isExcludedFromBackupKey` is present/valid, and create that file if it's not there at startup.

Files in the document dir with that flag are removed when a backup is restored.

```swift
var resourceURL = documentFileURL
var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = excludedFromBackup
try resourceURL.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
```